# Finding integers ending in 007 relatively prime

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, chinese-remainder-theorem

Can someone grade my proof for this problem:

---

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that there exists a positive integer $m > 1000$ with the following two properties: $m$'s last 3 digits are 007, and $m$ is relatively prime to $n$.

---

*Proof:*
Consider $2$ cases, $\gcd(n, 1000) = 1$, and $\gcd(n, 1000) > 1$.

**Case 1:** $\gcd (n, 1000) = 1$. Let us choose an $m$ such that
$$m \equiv 1 \pmod{n}.$$
We also know that $m \equiv 7 \pmod{1000}$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT), we can guarantee the existence of such  an $m$ since $n$ and $1000$ are relatively prime.

**Case 2:** $\gcd(n, 1000) > 1$. This case implies $n$ is divisible by $2$ or $5$. Thus we let rewrite $n$ as $n=2^x 5^y k$, where $x, y > 0$, and $\gcd(k, 1000) = 1$. Note that it suffices to show that $m$ is coprime to $k$, since $m$ is already coprime to $2$ and $5$ (ends in $007$). We can choose an $m$ that is congruent to $1 \pmod k$. We have the system
$$\begin{cases} m\equiv 7 \pmod{1000} & \\ m\equiv 1 \pmod{k} \end{cases}.$$
By CRT, we are guaranteed a solution for such an $m$, and thus we are done. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Looks good.  Small point:  you can't require that both $x,y>0$ in case $2$.  And maybe the whole thing is simpler if you just allow $x,y≥0$ and handle both cases at once.

Comment: OK, thanks! Will change.

Comment: A nice way to prove this claim without Dirichlet's theorem about primes in arithmetic progressions. With this theorem, we can even strengthen the claim.